# I am trying to save the output of linux server command to excel file using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, openpyxl

I am trying to login multiple linux server and execute some commamnd and save the output of that command into new Excel file for each server.

In the below code I am loggin multiple servers and excecuting command `cat /etc/passwd` and trying to save this output in a separate Excel file.

However I got the correct output but I am not able to save it in to Excel file.

```
import xlsxwriter

cred = open("creds.csv","r")
for i in cred.readlines():
    # Get users from cat /etc/passwd
    users = ...
    users ="".join(users)
    print(users)
    row = 1
    col = 0
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook("%s.xlsx"%ls[3],"w")
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
    for name in (users):
        worksheet.write(row, col, name)
        #worksheet.write(row, col + 1, score)
        row += 1
cred.close()
```

I am getting desired out from linux server but not able to save it to excel file.
But while saving to excel getting below error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\mukes\OneDrive\Documents\Script\obsolute_path", line 27, in <module>
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook("%s.xlsx"%ls[3],"w")
  File "C:\Users\mukes\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\workbook.py", line 75, in __init__
    self.tmpdir = options.get('tmpdir', None)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
PS C:\Users\mukes\OneDrive\Documents\Script>
```

Comment: As you are getting your error in one specific line and it has nothing to do with your output, please edit your question to write the [*minimal* reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Not related to your question, but you are not closing your `Workbook` files.

Comment: Not related to your question but your loop `for name in users` might not work as expected as `users` is a string. When iterating a string you get each character.

Comment: Not related to your question, but I would discourage the string interpolation using the percentage. I would recommend [fstrings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/). Use them to get the name of the xlsx file. But I would say there is no need of using string interpolation in `p.connect`.

Comment: Try building the filename of the XLSX file in a variable and printing that variable before calling `workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(VARIABLE,"w")`

Answer (score 1):

With just one Google search you will find the documentation of [`xlsxwriter`](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/workbook.html).You are passing your options as a string. That's why the the code complains about a string. The documentation says that `Workbook` expects a dictionary.

In the documentation I linked you will see there is no need to specify you want to open your Workbook in writing mode. The library is called *writer*, that's its behavior by default.